# Lat/Long to UTM conversion failing for dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, utm

The error `OutOfRangeError: latitude out of range (must be between 80 deg S and 84 deg N)"` appears when I use the `utm.from latlon()` function on a dataframe.

When I try it for a single lat/long, however, it returns the result.
I'm not sure what's going on.

e.g. dataframe

```
    Lat          Lon
0   49.183630   -121.936812
1   43.901052   -78.939154
2   43.887452   -78.871573
3   42.882137   -82.445210
4   43.372565   -79.762019
```

My Lat/Long is not reversed, as I checked.

Let's say utm function is defined as:

```
def f(x,y):
  return utm.from_latlon(x,y)
```

And I am calling the function as:

`dataframe.apply(lambda row: f(row['Lat'], row['Lon']), axis=1)`

Comment: how is utm.from_latlon() defined?

Comment: also curious why utm discriminates against coordinates near the poles

Comment: I have provided some more context in the question along with how I have defined the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use [utm](https://pypi.org/project/utm/) package:

```
import pandas as pd
import utm

df = pd.read_csv('latlon.csv')
df['utm'] = df.apply(lambda row: utm.from_latlon(*row), axis=1)
utm_cols = ['easting', 'northing', 'zone_number', 'zone_letter']
for n, col in enumerate(utm_cols):
    df[col] = df['utm'].apply(lambda location: location[n])
df = df.drop('utm', axis=1)
print(df)
```

output

```
         Lat         Lon        easting      northing  zone_number zone_letter
0  49.183630 -121.936812  577477.332853  5.448413e+06           10           U
1  43.901052  -78.939154  665502.266670  4.862947e+06           17           T
2  43.887452  -78.871573  670968.577419  4.861574e+06           17           T
3  42.882137  -82.445210  381977.464091  4.748739e+06           17           T
4  43.372565  -79.762019  600294.444939  4.802933e+06           17           T
```

Comment: Then check your data, obviously there is problem with the data.